# UI Buttons Not Showing Methods

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I want to make a UI that gives the player the option to continue playing the game (closing out the menu), or to go to the main menu. The code worked fine before, but today, I loaded it up, and saw that all my code was not compiling due to a different script I was working on. So, I removed the script components, and tried again.

I followed the [recommended advice listed here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/798406/unity-46-button-onclicks-functions-not-showing.html), and it worked before - but now it is not working. I have no idea what I did wrong. Attached are some pictures I took, along with the code. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class controls the 'Resume Game' Button. When the button is pressed, it removes the menu, and allows the game to continue.
/// </summary>

public class ResumeButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isPaused = false;
    public GameObject menu;

    public void ResumeButtonClicked()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        menu.SetActive(isPaused);
            print("It is not paused!");
            isPaused = false;
    }

    public void MainMenuButton()//There is only one button in the scene, this was code I was planning to add in. I am keeping it in here just in case it has any effect on the answer.
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("TestScene2");
    }
}
```

Methods Not Appearing:

[image: Methods Not Appearing]

Comment: Going back would be much easier if you would use svn or git.

Comment: Did you add the ResumeButton script back to your ButtonController?

Comment: @Oliver Maybe, but hindsight is 20/20. So, I need to focus on fixing on the problem now, instead of figuring out how to save code for the future.

JamesHogle Yes, I did. No dice.

Comment: If you don't have a version control system, I would set up a new (empty) project and start copying parts from the not working to the vanilla system and after each step checking if it works as expected. Then you maybe get a clue where the error is.

Comment: Thankfully, I did have an older version of the file saved, so I was able to use that. I will keep this question open so that I can find out what happened to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not comment yet, so here is my "comment": 
Make sure that the ResumeButton MonoBehaviour is saved as a ResumeButton.cs script (the cs file and the class name need to be the same). Also double check that the object you are providing to the onClick eventlistener list is indeed the object that has got the ResumeButton MonoBehaviour script attached to it.

At the moment I can see from the image you provided that you have a ButtonController script attached to the gameobject that you are trying to call from the onClick event, which will only show you functions you made public in the ButtonController.cs script.